# "países/zonas de riesgo" vs. "países terceros"

Tags: significado

Quisiera confirmar si "países/zonas de riesgo" y "países terceros" son lo mismo en "Compruebe, para rellenar el Formulario de Control Sanitario, si su país de inicio de viaje está en el listado de países/zonas de riesgo. Si procede de un país tercero, en primer lugar, debe comprobar si puede viajar a España en el botón". Aquí está el [enlace](https://www.mscbs.gob.es/profesionales/saludPublica/ccayes/alertasActual/nCov/spth.htm) . Me siento muy confundido ... ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que sé, un país tercero es cualquier país que no es el de procedencia. En este caso, se refiere a cualquier país que no fuera España o que no sea de la UE (según afirma @wimi en [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39656/pa%C3%8Dses-de-riesgo))

Por lo tanto, un país/zona de riesgo no es lo mismo que un país tercero.

Es decir, la primera frase pide consultar el formulario para asegurarse de si el país del que saldrá está en un listado, en este caso de países de riesgo. La segunda frase refuerza la idea de que todo este proceso sólo debe hacerse si la persona sale de un país que no es de la Unión Europea, y que se puede comprobar rápidamente con solo pulsar un botón.

Ojalá esto te haya servido, un saludo.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones y sí que me han servido mucho! Saludos

Comment: ¡Un placer! Cualquier duda, aquí estamos.

Comment: Añadí una corrección a la respuesta, mea culpa.